# EF 6 generated non-clustered primary key with data annotation?

Tags: entity-framework

I noticed the EF 6 that could specify a property non-clustered with Index attribute.
how to generate non-clustered primary key with data annotation?  I use Guid as primary key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create non clustered index on primary key entity framework 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475545/create-non-clustered-index-on-primary-key-entity-framework-6-0)

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855046/non-clustered-primary-key-entity-framework-code-first

Comment: This (quite old question) has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37926520/2298807 Basically: You cannot do this for now. Please use the hints in the answer there.