# create non clustered index on primary key entity framework 6.0

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24924752/entity-framework-code-first-define-the-non-clustered-key-for-this-entitytype), which states that it is not possible to create a primary key with non clustered index via code first. Is this still the case?

Ideally, I would like to specify via EntityTypeConfiguration, that my primary key (Guid) has a non-clustered index and there is another column (int) with a clustered index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Entity Framework 6.1, how can I use the IndexAttribute to define a clustered index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813137/in-entity-framework-6-1-how-can-i-use-the-indexattribute-to-define-a-clustered)

Comment: @Korayem who says I use EF 6.1?

Comment: you tagged the question entity-framework-6 so I presumed 6.1. I edited the title and removed the duplicate request.

Comment: Very much appreciated.

Comment: For the benefit of searchers, I created a related post for EntityFramework Core, which also enables this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004292/create-a-non-clustered-index-in-entity-framework-core

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK this is not possible with EntityTypeConfiguration. However you can do this with Code-First migrations. Working example:

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid Id
    { get; set; }

    public int Price
    { get; set; }
}

class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products
    { get; set; }
}

public partial class InitialCreate : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Products",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Guid(nullable: false),
                    Price = c.Int(nullable: false),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id, clustered: false)
            .Index(t => t.Price, clustered: true);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropIndex("dbo.Products", new[] { "Price" });
        DropTable("dbo.Products");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products] (
    [Id]    UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    [Price] INT              NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Products] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Price]
    ON [dbo].[Products]([Price] ASC);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have found something along those lines. I presume this is still the case then. I wait a bit longer before I accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with your `OnModelCreating` method like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity(entityTypeName)
    .HasKey(nameof(ClassName.Id))
    .ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);
```