# Non Clustered Primary Key Entity Framework Code First

Tags: indexing, entity-framework-6

In Entity Framework Code First approach, can we define the Primary Key as non-clustered index and a combination of few other fields as clustered index.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EntityTypeConfiguration does not provide a means of setting the Primary Key as a non-clustered index, but you can complete this by altering the initial migration used for table creation. There is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813137/in-entity-framework-6-1-how-can-i-use-the-indexattribute-to-define-a-clustered).

Here is an example of how to specify a clustered multiple-column index using attributes:

```
[Index("IX_ColumnOneTwo", 1, IsClustered = true)]
public int ColumnOne { get; set;}

[Index("IX_ColumnOneTwo", 2, IsClustered = true)]
public int ColumnTwo { get; set; }
```

and an example of how to complete this using model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassOne>() 
            .Property(t => t.ColumnOne) 
            .HasColumnAnnotation( 
                     "Index",  
                     new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_ColumnOneTwo") { IsClustered = true }));
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassOne>() 
            .Property(t => t.ColumnTwo) 
            .HasColumnAnnotation( 
                     "Index",  
                     new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_ColumnOneTwo") { IsClustered = true }));
```

Answer (score 18):

EF 6.2 resolved this issue. Currently, it's in beta state, but it works.

First, upgrade your EF to 6.2:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.2.0-beta1 -Pre
```

Then, in the `OnModelCreating` method, set the IsClustered to `false` for the primary key:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Receipt>().HasKey(r => r.RecId, config => config.IsClustered(false) );
```

Comment: The version 6.2.0 is now final, no longer beta.
This answer worked perfectly. 
I updated from 6.1.3 to 6.2.0 just to do this and had no problems. +1

Answer (score 5):

There is a solution for Entity Framework Core Code First by overriding OnModelCreating in DbContext

```
  p.HasKey(b => b.ColumnId).ForSqlServerIsClustered(false);
```

This code will generate migration like this:

```
 table.PrimaryKey("PK_Columns", x => x.ColumnId)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Clustered", false);
```

Comment: EF Core (using 7+ in .net 6, but might be available in earlier versions) you use:

modelBuilder.Entity<EntityType>().HasKey(a => a.Id).IsClustered(false);

Answer (score 1):

`Radenko Zec`'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39745753/2780791) is very useful also in EF Core. I will build upon it to provide a full solution for controlling the naming and also include an identity if needed. I will pick an example from one of my projects:

### NLog

```
NLogId - Primary Key, non-clustered, identity
EnteredDate - Clustered index
<other columns>
```

In EF Core you need to:

1. Use `[Key]` attribute to decorate NLogId property
2. Use db context `OnModelCreating` override to customize your keys:

   ```
   entity
       .HasKey(p => p.NlogId)
       .ForSqlServerIsClustered(false).HasName("PK_NLog");

   entity
       .HasIndex(p => p.EnteredDate)
       .ForSqlServerIsClustered(true).HasName("IDX_NLog_EnteredDate");
   ```
3. Double check that identity code is generated (it is way harder to add identity afterwards):

   ```
   migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
       name: "NLog",
       columns: table => new
       {
           NLogId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
               .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
   ```